Ошибка elif питон
Учусь программировать на питоне (знаний очень мало), сделал код по гайду Хауди Хо, но написав вторую часть кода вылезла ошибка elif, не знаю как решить,
код ниже, пишите не только как исправить код, а ещё напишите исправленный отрывок кода, заранее спасибо
import telebot
import config
import random

from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    stik1 = open('/storage/emulated/0/Documents/bot/Эхо бот/stickers/stik 1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, stik1) # Отправить стикер после получения команды /start
    
    #Клавиатура
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(" Вывести рандомное число")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton(" Как дела?")
    
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    
    
    bot_send_message(message.chat.id, "Дароу, {0.first_name}, ты теперь ты пользуешься ботом, !\nЯ - <b>{1first_name}</b>, Крута, да?".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), 
    parse_mode= 'html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Вывести рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, stik(random.randint(0.,100)))
            elif message.text == ' Как дела?':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ужесно! Я так хочу тебя!! Но тебя рядом НЕЕЕЕТ")
                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Обрубок пениса, ты нормально писать умеешь?")
                    
#Запуск
bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)


Отступы elif и дальше поправьте

Скажи по подробнее

@Ярослав Радев, почему вы обращаетесь к незнакомому человеку на ты?

‍♂️ буду теперь на вы обращаться

Python чувствителен к табуляции, поэтому очень важно размещать блоки кода относительно друг друга с правильной табуляцией, это указывает интерпретатору на вложенность тех или иных конструкций.
Блоки elif и else должны иметь на том же уровне вложенности блок if.
Иcправьте:
if message.text == ' Вывести рандомное число':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, stik(random.randint(0.,100)))
    elif message.text == ' Как дела?':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ужесно! Я так хочу тебя!! Но тебя рядом НЕЕЕЕТ")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Обрубок пениса, ты нормально писать умеешь?")

на:
if message.text == ' Вывести рандомное число':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, stik(random.randint(0.,100)))
elif message.text == ' Как дела?':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ужесно! Я так хочу тебя!! Но тебя рядом НЕЕЕЕТ")
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Обрубок пениса, ты нормально писать умеешь?")

Лучше чем хауди-хо

Спасибо большое

И извините за странный текст
